# YouTube API V3 Get Overall Ratings for Video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In YouTube's V2 API one could obtain a video's rating from the following tag

`<gd:rating average="4.254023" numRaters="20509">`

I am not finding this information contained within the new V3 api however.

I am using the videos api.  I reviewed all of the available properties that can be returned at this location but while I am finding information about "ratings", that information pertains to movie and tv ratings, not how the video was rated.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties

Does anyone have experience with this that may know?

Comment: Did you ever find solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you posted, see the `statistics` object, specifically `statistics.likeCount` and `statistics.dislikeCount`.

Comment: ... op didn't actually look at the api. `contentDetails.contentRating` is also a likely choice.

Comment: @adam_bear, That's not the same `rating` we 're talking about. It's the `safeRating`, not a number from `likeCount` at all.

Comment: `contentDetails.contentRating.mpaaRating` would return G, PG, PG-13, R, etc. which sounds to me a lot like 'information pertains to movie and tv ratings' Even if this wasn't the function call OP wanted, the API is pretty clear